# After second click function is working for sorting in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

i have done sorting of list tag alphabetically in javascript/jquery it works when i click on second times. i mean on first time click it work for few second (less than one second) and back to unsorted but  after second click it work properly.

**My sorting function is**

```
function status() {
    var mylist = $('ul');
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).find('.Status-For-Sorting').text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).find('.Status-For-Sorting').text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $.each(listitems, function (idx, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
}
```

And i define that function in deviceready like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {
    $().ready(function () {
        $("#sort-button-status").click(status);
    }
}
```

*******HTML******

```
<a  value="sort" id="sort-button-status" class="sort-button-status">status</a>
```

tell me guys where i am wrong this code is sorting properly according to status, but after second click ..

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` (or the shortcut `$(function(){ ... })`) instead of `$().ready(function(){ ... })`, you seem to be mixing the two options listed [in the jQuery docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.appendTo()` to apply sorted list to `mylist`:

```
function status()
{  
    var mylist = $('ul');
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).find('.Status-For-Sorting').text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).find('.Status-For-Sorting').text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(mylist);
}
```

Comment: Hey **Bhusan** i tried your code but that is no not working .. i mean i did append in last of return value .apendTo(mylist) but this function is not working;

Comment: it is `appendTo` and not `apendTo`, please check your spelling

Comment: sorry  yes i used appendTo(), it was my mistake that i wrote apendTo in comment rather than appendTo() ..